# c# is WebRequest.Create gives me a URL encoded?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have been giving an API to send SMS, the API states that I should use this url

```
http://<server>:<port>/bulksms/bulksms?
username=XXXX&password=YYYYY&type=Y&dlr=Z&destination=QQQQQQQQQ&sour
ce=RRRR&message=SSSSSSSS<&url=KKKK>
```

Where **message** and **url** must be **URL-UTF-8 encoded**.

what I did is creating that url like this:

```
string urlSMS = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/bulksms/bulksms?username={2}&password={3}&type={4}&dlr={5}&destination={6}&source={7}&message={8}&url=0",
server, port, username, password, type, dlr, destination, source, message);
```

then I called that URL like this:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(urlSMS);
                wr.Timeout = 3500;
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```

however, I kept having **timeout error** message, I checked everything that is why i am asking. i need to know if

```
WebRequest.Create(urlSMS)
```

gives me a `URL-UTF-8` encoded or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It looks like WebRequest.Create(url) will UTF-8 encode the url.

When I try this:

```
WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/search?q=♥");
```

I can see that the internal representation if the URI is encoded: `r.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri` returns `http://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%99%A5`

Whereas `r.RequestUri.ToString()` returns `http://www.google.com/search?q=♥`.